# Why and when to use @JvmStatic with companion objects?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, kotlin-companion

I'm trying to understand the difference between using/not using @JvmStatic, and when I should use either one.

So, with Kotlin and Java, I can do this:

`TestKotlin.kt`

```
class TestKotlin {
    companion object {
        val someString = "hello world"
    }
}
```

Which is then called by Java, like this:

`TestJava.java`

```
public class TestJava {
    String kotlinStaticString = TestKotlin.Companion.getSomeString();
}
```

but then, there's this option 2:

`TestKotlin.kt` v2

```
class TestKotlin {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic  // <-- notice the @JvmStatic annotation
        val someString = "hello world"
    }
}
```

And then, call it from Java, like this:

`TestJava.java` v2

```
public class TestJava {
    String kotlinStaticString = TestKotlin.getSomeString();
}
```

So my questions are:

- Are these 2 cases any different, in terms of behavior or memory allocation?
- Is there a preference on which one to use?
- Do both create a pseudo static singleton object, like Java static does?

Thanks!

Answer (score 109, accepted):

The behavior of the `@JvmStatic` annotation is explained in detail in [the documentation](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#static-methods). When reading the documentation, you should assume that it gives you all the important information, and behavior differences that are not mentioned in the documentation do not exist.

In this case, the documentation says:

> If you use this annotation, the compiler will generate both a static method in the enclosing class of the object and an instance method in the object itself.

In other words, the effect of the annotation is that it tells the compiler to *generate an additional method*.

Does the documentation mention that there is any difference in behavior or memory allocation? It does not. Therefore, it's safe to assume that there is none.

Is there a preference on which one to use? Normally, an API is declared in one place and used from multiple places. If you're calling a method from Java, then you should declare it as `@JvmStatic`, because adding the `@JvmStatic` annotation in one place will allow you to leave out multiple `.Companion` references in multiple places.

Do both create a pseudo static singleton object, like Java static does? This question does not make sense, because Java static does not create a "pseudo static singleton object". If you declare a static method in a Java class, and then call this method, no objects will be created.

Comment: @TooManyEduardos "... memory allocation" - yes. You have rudimentary companion object everywhere you try (or need) to implement **stateless** "Util" class and you do it in "java idiom". This think illustrated in question https://stackoverflow.com/q/54104719/3926506

Comment: >  When reading the documentation, you should assume that it gives you all the important information, and behaviour differences that are not mentioned in the documentation do not exist.   You must be joking?   Why is this answer so condescending?

Answer (score 111):

A `companion object` is an instance of a real `class` called `Companion`. So, when you call the Kotlin code from Java, an object of the `Companion` class is first instantiated behind the scenes. To understand this, let's consider a simple example.

---

### Behind the scenes without `@JvmStatic`

**Kotlin code**

```
class Plant {
    companion object {
        fun waterAll() { }
    }
}
```

**Decompiled Java code**

```
public final class Plant {

   public static final Plant.Companion Companion = new Plant.Companion();

   public static final class Companion {

      public final void waterAll() { }

      private Companion() { }
   }
}
```

As you can see in the simplified decompiled Java code above, a class named `Companion` is generated to represent the `companion object`. The class `Plant` holds the singleton instance `new Plant.Companion()` of the class `Plant.Companion`. The instance is also named as `Companion`. This is the reason you need to call the functions/properties of the `companion object` in Java using the `Plant.Companion`:

```
Plant.Companion.waterAll();
```

---

### Behind the scenes with `@JvmStatic`

**Kotlin code**

```
class Plant {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun waterAll() { }
    }
}
```

**Decompiled Java code**

```
public final class Plant {

   public static final Plant.Companion Companion = new Plant.Companion();

   @JvmStatic
   public static final void waterAll() { Companion.waterAll();}

   public static final class Companion {
      @JvmStatic
      public final void waterAll() { }

      private Companion() { }
   }
}
```

When you annotate a function of a `companion object` with `@JvmStatic` in Kotlin, a pure `static` function `waterAll()` is generated in addition to the non static function `waterAll()`. So, now you are able to call the function without the `Companion` name which is more idiomatic to Java:

```
Plant.waterAll();
```

---

### Singleton

The singleton pattern is generated in both cases. As you can see, in both cases, the `Companion` instance holds the singleton object `new Plant.Companion()` and the constructor is made `private` to prevent multiple instances.

The Java `static` keyword does not create the singletons. You will get the singleton feature only if you create a `companion object` in Kotlin and then use it from Java. To get singleton from Java, you'll need to write the singleton pattern, the code for which looks like the decompiled Java code shown above.

---

### Performance

There is no performance gain or loss in terms of memory allocation. The reason is that, as you can see in the code above, the extra `static` function that is generated delegates its work to the non static function `Companion.waterAll()`. This means, creation of the `Companion` instance is required in both the cases, with `@JvmStatic` as well as without `@JvmStatic`.

The behaviour of both the setups is the same apart from the extra method that is generated. In Android, if you worry about the method count, you may need to keep an eye on this because an extra copy is created for each annotated function.

---

### When to use `@JvmStatic`

When you know that your Kotlin code won't be used in Java, you don't have to worry about adding the `@JvmStatic` annotation. This keeps your code cleaner. However, if your Kotlin code is called from Java, it makes sense to add the annotation. This will prevent your Java code from polluting with the name `Companion` everywhere.

It's not like an additional keyword on either side. If you add `@JvmStatic` in one place, you can prevent writing the extra `Companion` word in thousands of places, wherever you call that function. This is especially useful for library creators, if they add `@JvmStatic` in their Kotlin library, the users of that library won't have to use the `Companion` word in their Java code.

---

That's it! Hopefully that helps get the clearer picture of the `@JvmStatic`.

Comment: It's worth noting that there is also a difference in how you'd call such methods from C/C++/JNI, as calling static methods is usually a bit simpler than calling instance methods (even if the instance is a static singleton, `Companion` in this case).

Answer (score 15):

You place the function in the "companion object".

So the java code like this:

```
class DemoClass {
  public static int myMethod() { return 1; }
}
```

will become

```
class DemoClass {
  companion object {
     fun myMethod() : Int = 1
  }
}
```

You can then use it from inside Kotlin code as

```
DemoClass.myMethod();
```

But from within Java code, you would need to call it as

```
DemoClass.Companion.myMethod();
```

(Which also works from within Kotlin.)

If you don't like having to specify the `Companion` bit you can either add a `@JvmStatic` annotation or name your companion class.

From the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#companion-objects):

> ## Companion Objects
>
> An object declaration inside a class can be marked with the companion 
>   keyword:
>
> ```
> class MyClass {
>    companion object Factory {
>        fun create(): MyClass = MyClass()
>    }
> }
> ```
>
> Members of the companion object can be called by using simply the class 
>   name as the qualifier:
>
> ```
> val instance = MyClass.create()
> ```
>
> ...
>
> However, on the JVM you can have members of companion objects generated 
>   as real static methods and fields, if you use the `@JvmStatic`
>   annotation.  See the Java interoperability section for more details.

Adding the `@JvmStatic` annotation looks like this

```
class DemoClass {
  companion object {
    @JvmStatic
    fun myMethod() : Int = 1;
  }
}
```

and then a will exist as a real Java static function, accessible from
both Java and kotlin as `DemoClass.myMethod()`.

If it is just disliked by the `Companion` name, then you can also 
provide an explicit name for the companion object looks like this:

```
class DemoClass {
  companion object Blah {
    fun myMethod() : Int = 1;
  }
}
```

which will let you call it from Kotlin in the same way, but
from java like `DemoClass.Blah.myMethod()` (which will also work in Kotlin).

Comment: yeah i know how to use it either way. i want to know if there's a difference between them, primarily on how they handle memory

Answer (score 3):

In Kotlin, the `companion` object can be us used to imitate static behaviour, calls look like static calls in Java, the `“Companion“` isn’t part of if. If used in Java though, the `companion` object has to be named, unless `@JvmStatic` is applied. It’d look less idiomatic otherwise.

```
TestKotlin.getSomeString() //this should be preferred whenever possible
```

Stated in the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#companion-objects):

> ## Companion Objects
>
> An object declaration inside a class can be marked with the companion 
>   keyword:
>
> ```
> class MyClass {
>    companion object Factory {
>        fun create(): MyClass = MyClass()
>    }
> }
> ```
>
> Members of the companion object can be called by using simply the class 
>   name as the qualifier:
>
> ```
> val instance = MyClass.create()
> ```
>
> ...
>
> However, on the JVM you can have members of companion objects generated 
>   as real static methods and fields, if you use the `@JvmStatic`
>   annotation.  See the Java interoperability section for more details.

Note that it will generate an **additional** method as stated [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#static-methods):

> If you use this annotation, the compiler will generate both a static method in the enclosing class of the object and an instance method in the object itself.

Let's see an **example**:

The following class

```
class Outer {
    companion object {
        fun callMe() = ""
    }
}
```

looks like this on bytecode level, here represented as Java code:

```
@Metadata(...)
public final class Outer {
   public static final Outer.Companion Companion = new Outer.Companion((DefaultConstructorMarker)null);

   @Metadata(...)
   public static final class Companion {
      @NotNull
      public final String callMe() {
         return "";
      }

      private Companion() {
      }

      // $FF: synthetic method
      public Companion(DefaultConstructorMarker $constructor_marker) {
         this();
      }
   }
}
```

If `@JvmStatic` is being applied to `callMe` method though, the bytecode changes to the following:

```
@Metadata(...)
public final class Outer {
   public static final Outer.Companion Companion = new Outer.Companion((DefaultConstructorMarker)null);

   @JvmStatic
   @NotNull
   public static final String callMe() {
      return Companion.callMe();
   }

   @Metadata(...)
   public static final class Companion {
      @JvmStatic
      @NotNull
      public final String callMe() {
         return "";
      }

      private Companion() {
      }

      // $FF: synthetic method
      public Companion(DefaultConstructorMarker $constructor_marker) {
         this();
      }
   }
}
```

You can see, correctly documented, the static `callMe` function, as part of `Outer` is generated:

```
@JvmStatic
@NotNull
public static final String callMe() {        
    return Companion.callMe();
}
```

Comment: right, but is there a difference in memory allocation, or overall usage from using either or?

Comment: An additional method will be generated on bytecode level, which should be ok on most platforms I guess

Comment: kind of. its an additional keyword on either side. if I use the `@JvmStatic`, I can skip the `Companion` call in the java side, but if I skip the `@JvmStatic` I have to add the `Companion` on the other side. Its sixes either way, but I want to know if there's a memory usage difference

Comment: I added an example which shows some byte code repesentations

Answer (score 2):

Unlike others, I do not think that the effect of `@JvmStatic` and `@JvmField` is explained enough in the Kotlin documentation. It was unclear to me until I saw the effect.

The other answers cover the functions, but not *fields*. And because the question is not explicitly limited, let me add:

---

Normally, if you work within Kotlin, you do not need these, because Kotlin's take on "static" is quite consistent and the companion objects cover almost all purposes for which Java uses `static`.

The main use cases, when you need `@JvmStatic` and `@JvmField`, are:

- when you use Kotlin together with Java code, because you don't want to refer to `*.Companion.*` from Java.
- When you use libraries which use reflection on static fields.

Because Kotlin, for the fields in a `companion object`, creates a `private` field in the `Companion` class, and wraps it with getter/setter. But your Java code or library needs a real `static` field in the class. (Some Java libraries may support Kotlin's `Companion`, though).

Therefore, Kotlin comes with these two:

- `@JvmStatic` makes the *property* available in the class in which you have the companion object. That means, there is a getter/setter, but the fields is still private.
- `@JvmField` goes "further" and only adds the field. Getter and setter is not generated.

(I did not find a way to have both the `public` field and the getter and setter. This caused me some headaches when I used 2 libraries, one needed the field and one only worked with properties.)

```kotlin
class Foo { companinon object { val x: Int? } }
```

```java
public class Foo {
   static class Companion { private Int x = null; } 
}
```

---

```kotlin
class Foo { companinon object { @JvmStatic val x: Int? } }
```

```java
public class Foo {
   public static getX() { return Foo.Companion.x } // * Simplified
   static class Companion { private Int x = null; } 
}
```

---

```kotlin
class Foo { companinon object { @JvmField val x: Int? } }
```

```java
public class Foo {
   public static Int x = null;
   static class Companion { private Int x = null; } 
}
```

- Simplified: Actually, the `Foo` class has a static instance of Companion and the Foo's getter calls the instance's getter.

But in the end, you might find out that you should not have used a static field in the first place. Static fields in Java are there historically as a shortcut for the C++ programmers who would not accept hard-core OOP Java when it was introduced.