# Kotlin: IllegalAccessError for sortedBy { it.field } while accessing a property of a data class

Tags: android, sorting, kotlin, data-class

Everything as working correctly, but a few days ago I noticed that sorting was incorrect. After debugging I saw this message

> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Field '*.TagModel.isFollowed' is
>   inaccessible to class
>   'Generated_for_debugger_class$generated_for_debugger_fun$$inlined$sortedBy$1'
>   (declaration of
>   'Generated_for_debugger_class$generated_for_debugger_fun$$inlined$sortedBy$1'
>   appears in /data/user/0/*.debug/Anonymous-DexFile@1099533879.jar).

The code is `this.tags.sortedWith(compareBy { it.isFollowed })`. Has something changed in Kotlin? What can be an issue here?
`tags` is a list of data classes, nothing special. It has `@Parcelize` annotation, would that affect it at all? Seems weird.

Comment: Do you use multidex?

Comment: yes, indeed I do.

Comment: I found same error `IllegalAccessError` here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51435580/illegalaccesserror-method-is-inaccessible-to-class. Maybe it will help

Comment: Were you able to solve it? I have the same issue.

Comment: Were you able to solve it? I have the same issue.